# I am getting a name error for the following input stocks using functions

Tags: python, function

```
def main():

    def input_stocks():
        tot_pr = 0

        while True:
            stock_name = input("\nEnter Stock Name: ")
            shares_bought = float(input("\nNumber of Shares bought: "))
            stock_pp = float(input("Enter stock purchasing price: "))
            stock_sp = float(input("Enter stock selling price: "))
            commision = float(input("Enter broker Commision: "))
            peaceout = input("Continue or exit? (case sensitive):")
            if peaceout == 'quit':
                return stock_name,shares_bought,stock_pp,stock_sp,commision


    def calc():
        amount_paid = shares_bought * stock_pp

        paid_commision_bought = amount_paid * commision

        stock_sold = shares_bought * stock_sp

        paid_commision_sold = stock_sold * commision

        pl = (stock_sold - paid_commision_sold) - (amount_paid + paid_commision_bought)

        tot_pr = tot_pr + pl

    def output():
        print("\nStock Name:", stock_name)
        print("Amount paid: $", format(amount_paid,',.2f'))
        print("Paid commision bought: $", format(paid_commision_bought,',.2f'))
        print("Stock sold $", format(stock_sold,',.2f'))
        print("Paid commision sold: $", format(paid_commision_sold,',.2f'))
        print("Profit or Loss: $", format(pl,',.2f'))
        print("Total Profit thus far: $", format(tot_pr,',.2f'))
        return stock_name,amount_paid,paid_commision_bought,paid_commision_sold,pl,tot_pr

    output()
main()
```

> > >
> >     NameError: name 'stock_name' is not defined (I'd assume others won't be defined as well...
> >
> > > 

What can I do to fix this error, and how can I prevent this in the future? I am quite new to this so I want to learn from my mistakes

Comment: it looks like your indentation is off to start with (but thats probably just in the post)

Comment: Yeah it is correctly indented in my program, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stock_name` and the other variables in `output()` will not be defined until the `input_stocks()` function is actually *run*. Just defining a function does not actually run it.

Comment: Consider encapsulating these as instance methods within a class, run the input_stocks method at instantiation, and storing stock_name, etc., as instance variables.

Comment: @manglano you should be commenting to the OP, not me. I doubt OP is at that level of programming yet to even understand what you said, but I agree that is a better way of going about it.

Comment: Correct, I am not that far into what I am learning to do that yet, nor do I grasp what Manglano has said. I have been fooling around and moving things around logically, and my calc function is now the one giving me problems, saying my constants (formulas I guess) are not defined. amount_paid = shares_bought * stock_pp
NameError: name 'shares_bought' is not defined'

Comment: I messed around a little more, and also had the problem that my program ran, did everything, but never printed.

Comment: `input_stocks` only makes the variables in its local scope ... they would still not be defined int the `output` method

Comment: So I need to pass them to the next function?

Comment: @Kevin You need to pass the different values between each function and actually run the various functions in order, among many other changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def load():
    tot_pr = 0
    peaceout = ''


    while peaceout != 'exit':
        stock_name = input("\nEnter Stock Name: ")    
        shares_bought = float(input("\nNumber of Shares bought: "))
        stock_pp = float(input("Enter stock purchasing price: "))
        stock_sp = float(input("Enter stock selling price: "))
        commision = float(input("Enter broker Commision: "))
        peaceout = input("Continue or exit? (case sensitive):")
        return stock_name,shares_bought,stock_pp,stock_sp,commision,tot_pr

def calc(shares_bought,stock_pp,stock_sp,commision,tot_pr):
    amount_paid = shares_bought * stock_pp
    paid_commision_bought = amount_paid * commision
    stock_sold = shares_bought * stock_sp
    paid_commision_sold = stock_sold * commision
    pl = (stock_sold - paid_commision_sold) - (amount_paid + paid_commision_bought)
    tot_pr = tot_pr + pl
    return amount_paid,paid_commision_bought,stock_sold,paid_commision_sold,pl,tot_pr


def output(stock_name,amount_paid,paid_commision_bought,stock_sold,paid_commision_sold,pl,tot_pr):
    print("\nStock Name:", stock_name)
    print("Amount paid: $", format(amount_paid,',.2f'))
    print("Paid commision bought: $", format(paid_commision_bought,',.2f'))
    print("Stock sold $", format(stock_sold,',.2f'))
    print("Paid commision sold: $", format(paid_commision_sold,',.2f'))
    print("Profit or Loss: $", format(pl,',.2f'))
    print("Total Profit thus far: $", format(tot_pr,',.2f'))
    return stock_name,amount_paid,paid_commision_bought,paid_commision_sold,pl,tot_pr

def main():

    stock_name,shares_bought,stock_pp,stock_sp,commision,tot_pr = load()
    amount_paid,paid_commision_bought,stock_sold,paid_commision_sold,pl,tot_pr = calc(shares_bought,stock_pp,stock_sp,commision,tot_pr)
    output(stock_name,amount_paid,paid_commision_bought,stock_sold,paid_commision_sold,pl,tot_pr)

main()
```

I rewrote my program, and the only problem now is it won't loop if I type in continue?

@Joran Beasley
@MattDMo